# Probabilistic, indeterministic and random in QM

Tags: philosophy-of-science, probability, quantum-physics, quantum-interpretations

This is a question about terminology used in QM since I need to clarify this aspect. Is “probabilistic” a synonym of “indeterministic”? And in case they are not synonyms, what do they exactly mean? And is “randomness” a synonym of “indeterminacy”?

Comment: Generally, "indeterministic" is broader than "probabilistic", indeterminacy can, in principle, be completely lawless, i.e. not obey even probabilistic laws. “Randomness” and “indeterminacy” might differ in some contexts (e.g. free will discussions), but in the context of QM all these distinctions are mostly moot.

Comment: And what abou the term “stochastic”? Is it, again, used as a synonym of “probabilistic”? @Conifold

Comment: "Stochastic" is usually used in the theory of random processes, and not in QM, but yes, more or less.

Comment: Thanks again @Conifold just another question when you said in the first answer that distinctions considered are not relevant in QM are you thinking about the indeterministic/probabilistic distinction or just the randomness/indeterminacy one?

Comment: All of them do not matter much.